# Combine Laravel Collections items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this collection with this elements:

```
Collection {#325 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▶]//element1
      1 => array:2 [▶]//element2
      2 => array:2 [▶]//element3
      3 => array:2 [▶]//element4
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▶]//element5
      1 => array:2 [▶]//element6
      2 => array:2 [▶]//element7
      3 => array:2 [▶]//element8
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▶]//element9
      1 => array:2 [▶]//element10
      2 => array:2 [▶]//element11
      3 => array:2 [▶]//elemen12
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I need combine this elements in only collection.

I want an result like this:

```
Collection {#325 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼

      0 => array:2 [▶]//element1
      1 => array:2 [▶]//element2
      2 => array:2 [▶]//element3
      3 => array:2 [▶]//element4
      4 => array:2 [▶]//element5
      5 => array:2 [▶]//element6
      6 => array:2 [▶]//element7
      7 => array:2 [▶]//element8
      8 => array:2 [▶]//element9
      9 => array:2 [▶]//element10
      10 => array:2 [▶]//element11
      11 => array:2 [▶]//elemen12
    ]
  ]
}
```

Each element1, element2, etc, contains other array like this:

```
   3 => array:2 [▼//element 3 for example
        "id" => 50
        "type" => "ARTICLE"
      ]
```

Is there any way to do this? I´m using Laravel 5.3 version and I not have idea about that collection function use for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-flatten) method:

```
$collection->flatten();
```

> The flatten method flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension

Comment: this method is not valid to me, return me the keys of my elements separateds:Collection {#326 ▼
  #items: array:24 [▼
    0 => 2638
    1 => "ARTICLE"
    2 => 2100
    3 => "ARTICLE"
    4 => 5407
    5 => "ARTICLE"
    6 => 2970
    7 => "ARTICLE"
    8 => 146
    9 => "CATEGORY"
    10 => 6186
    11 => "ARTICLE"
    12 => 164
    13 => "CATEGORY"
    14 => 1728
    15 => "ARTICLE"
    16 => 4481
    17 => "ARTICLE"
    18 => 1611
    19 => "ARTICLE"
    20 => 5345
    21 => "ARTICLE"
    22 => 50
    23 => "ARTICLE"
  ]
}

Comment: ah ok, I use ->flatten(1) and works perfectly, thanks!